# SQLAlchemy create index passing column names with keyword argument

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to create table index passing column names with keyword argument to Index constructor (for readability). Something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Index
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import SMALLINT, BIGINT

Base = declarative_base()

class Pages(Base):
    __tablename__ = "pages"

    id = Column(BIGINT(unsigned=True), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    scanner_id = Column(
        SMALLINT(5, unsigned=True), ForeignKey("scanners.scanner_id"))
    source_id = Column(
        SMALLINT(5, unsigned=True), ForeignKey("sources.source_id"))
    ...

    __table_args__ = (
        Index(name="scanner_id", 
              expressions=["scanner_id"]),
        Index(name="scanner_id_source_id", 
              expressions=["scanner_id", "source_id"], unique=True),
        ...
    )
```

I tried also `mysql_expressions` keyword, and `sqlalchemy.schema.Index` class with `columns` and `mysql_columns` keywords, but got the following errors:

```
TypeError: Additional arguments should be named <dialectname>_<argument>, 
got 'expression'
```

or

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Argument 'mysql_columns' is not 
accepted by dialect 'mysql' on behalf of <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Index'>
```